# How to work with assertEqual with parameterized types

Tags: testing, haskell, hunit

I'm trying to do the exercises in Real World Haskell in a TDD fashion, using [HUnit](http://hunit.sourceforge.net/). As you probably guessed I haven't gotten far yet so I'm an absolute beginner when it comes to Haskell. Given the following code how can I resolve the following error ghci produces:

> Ambiguous type variable `a' in the constraints:`
>   Show a'
>           arising from a use of `assertEqual' at List_Test.hs:6:27-58`
>   Eq a' arising from a use of `assertEqual' at List_Test.hs:6:27-58
>       Probable fix: add a type signature that fixes these type variable(s)

List_Test.hs:

```
module List_Test
where
import List
import Test.HUnit

fromEmptyList = TestCase $ assertEqual "" [] (toList (Nil))

main = runTestTT fromEmptyList
```

List.hs:

```
module List
where
data List a = Cons a (List a)
            | Nil
              deriving (Show)

toList Nil = []
toList (Cons a b) = (:) a (toList b)
```

I've tried adding type constraints to both the List declaration and the toList definition without success. A internet search did also not provide any information.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue is partially that GHC does not know that `toList Nil` will return an empty list.

```
*List> :i toList
toList :: List a -> [a]     -- Defined at List.hs:7:0-5
```

It only knows that it will return a list of type `a`, but it has no idea what `a` is -- hence the "ambiguous type variable a" message.  One way to work around this is to just specify the type of list that toList will return:

```
fromEmptyList = TestCase $ assertEqual "" [] (toList (Nil) :: [Int])
```

Changing that, and removing the first two lines of List_Test (it will not look for a `main` function in a named module that is not named `Main`), gave me this result:

```
$ runghc List_Test.hs 
Cases: 1  Tried: 1  Errors: 0  Failures: 0
```

Comment: thanks, was unaware of the syntax to specify the return type for a given call to a function.